# How do I add a second set of row names in R?

Tags: r

I have a set of around 750 measurements, sorted into 10 columns, with each row representing a decade. I've altered the row names ('times') to suit the dates, but I need a second set of row names for the sample ID. Is it possible to define two row name?

Can this be added as a column vector even if the data frame has been sorted into groups of 10?

```
data <- read.csv (file='Transpose.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ',');
require(reshape2)
melt(data)

times <- c(1940,1950,1960,1970,1980,1990,2000,2010,2020,2030,2040,2050,2060,2070,2080,2090,2100,2110,2120,2130,2140,2150,2160,2170,2180,2190,2200,2210,2220,2230,2240,2250,2260,2270,2280,2290,2300,2310,2320,2330,2340,2350,2360,2370,2380,2390,2400,2410,2420,2430,2440,2450,2460,2470,2480,2490,2500,2510,2520,2530,2540,2550,2560,2570,2580,2590,2600,2610,2620,2630,2640,2650,2660,2670,2680,2690,2700);

matrix1<- data.frame(X=data$Measurement, ind=rep(1:10, nrow(data)/10));

capture.output(print(unstack(matrix1, X~ind), print.gap=3, row.names=times), file="Transposed.txt")
```

Comment: Why does it have to be in rownames? Why not just in a column? Or turn your data to long format?

Comment: It could be another column. Is it possible to add one with a different number of variables (e.g. data 750, additional column would only have 75)? @Heroka

Comment: you could use `rep()` to replicate 10 times the 75 different names and put that in a column. would that be OK ?

Comment: @mpauly you might benefit from reading [ask] and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questionsg/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Makes it easier for others to help you.